# Can't remove item in NSMutableArray with directory names

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I want to check all the directories in my document folder and list those whose name is not in an NSArray called eventList. Evenlist is an array of ALAssetsGroup.
Here is the code:

```
    NSLog(@"eventList %@",eventList);

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];        
    NSMutableArray *tagsFolderList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tagsFolderList = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:tagsPath error:nil] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"tagsFolderList %@",tagsFolderList);


    if(([tagsFolderList count] > 0) && ([eventList count] > 0))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[eventList count]; i++) {
            NSString *eventName = [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
            NSLog(@"eventName %@",eventName);

            [tagsFolderList removeObjectIdenticalTo:eventName];
        }
```

Here are the logs:

```
    eventList (
        "ALAssetsGroup - Name:19 ao\U00fbt 2012, Type:Event, Assets count:27",
        "ALAssetsGroup - Name:21 ao\U00fbt 2012, Type:Event, Assets count:8",
        "ALAssetsGroup - Name:2 nov. 2012, Type:Event, Assets count:12",
        "ALAssetsGroup - Name:4 nov. 2012, Type:Event, Assets count:9"
    )
    tagsFolderList (
        "1 nov. 2012",
        "19 aou\U0302t 2012",
        "2 nov. 2012",
        "4 nov. 2012",
        "6 oct. 2012"
    )
    eventName 19 août 2012
```

Even when the names of ALAssetsGroup and directory are the same "4 nov. 2012" for ie I can't remove the object. I just try many string encode converting without success.

Any suggestion ?

Regards

Comment: How about "removeObject" instead of "removeObjectIdenticalTo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removeObjectIdenticalTo: compares object addresses, not string values.  So, even if the strings are the same character runs, they must be the exact same object.  If you want to compare those with a similar character run, use NSString's isEqualToString method.

Comment: Remember to mark it as an answer so that others will know the question has been answered.